# JPA mapping an java.io.File or java.nio.file.Path object to a STRING column

Tags: java, jpa, mapping, sqldatatypes

assume the following Entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private File path;

    private String someString;
}
```

which I want to map to such a table:

```
CREATE TABLE (id BIGINT, path VARCHAR, somestring VARCHAR);
```

The problem ist the mapping from `java.io.File` (or `java.nio.file.Path`) to a simple string representing the file path.
Is such a mapping possible with JPA?

Of course, I could define `path` as a string and let the client create the `File` or `Path` object. But it is much more handy to provide these objects directly in the entity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is `File` is more than just the path.  While it's serializable, it's not going to map into a VARCHAR. If you just want the path, you need to add make the file.getPath() part of the entity and the `File` object `@Transient`.  That way you can save the path to the DB and still have the `File` object when it's loaded.

Something like this:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Transient
    private File file;

    private String filePath;

    private String someString;


public void setFilePath(File file) {
    filePath = file.getPath();
}
```

}

Comment: While the File object is more than just the path, all I want to be stored in the DB is the path. I don't want to store the files content, therefore LOB is no option for me. What do you mean by _make the file.toString [...] and the File object @transient_? If i annote the file as transient, how am I able to define a mapping for it?

Comment: I've edited the answer with an example to show what I meant. The `@Transient` annotation keeps JPA from trying to persist that field. If you are concerned about when the filePath field is valid, you could use a `@PrePersist` interceptor to be sure it's populated.